# Locating a point where the two persons meet.

Tags: geometry

> Please see the following figure. Suppose two persons start moving from A to B, person 1 takes the route direct from A towards B while the person 2 takes the route from A to C and then to B. The speed of person 2 is twice as much as person 1. Suppose person 1 reaches point B before person 2 and waits for him there. Is it possible for the two persons to meet at a point between A and B on line AB such that none of the persons has to wait for the other one?
>   Is there a way I can mathematically prove that in the conditions given the point will always be outside the range AB, on the right side of B and can never be inside AB.
>
> [image]

What I have tried: I have tried different sets of coordinates but can never locate a point in between where the two persons meet without one waiting for the other.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You say person 2 walks from A to C, then to B.  So the only point on AB that he touches is B.  How could he meet person 1 at any other place?

Comment: The simplest solution would be if ABC is an equilateral triangle.  And then there is an ellipse such that A,B are foci and for all points on the ellipse the distance from A to C to B is constant.

Comment: What I mean is can the person 2 meet person 1 if he tries to deviate from its path along CB just so he can meet the person 1 before reaching point B. That is at a point on line AB before both reach B.

Comment: Ah, that's a horse of a different color.  If person 1 moves at speed 1, and person 2 moves at speed 2, then after m/2 units of time, person 2 is at C and person 1 is at a point D, m/2 units from A.  Can you construct a circle of radius t at D, and a circle of radius 2t at C, which intersect either other on the line AB?

Comment: What is t here?

Comment: I am trying to prove that in the conditions given the point will always be outside the range AB, on the right side of B and can never be inside AB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

We're told that, if person $P$ (traveling on edges $p_i$) and person $Q$ (on edges $q_i$, at twice $P$'s speed) were to meet at $B$, then $P$ would have to wait (presumably, a *strictly-positive* amount of time). We can write
$$2(p_1+p_2) < q_1 + q_2 + q_3 \tag{1}$$
If $Q$ were take a detour ($D$-tour?) at $D$ to meet $P$ simultaneously at $E$, then
$$2p_1 = q_1+q_2+q_3^\prime \tag{2}$$
Finally, by the Triangle Inequality (even in its lenient form), we have
$$q_3 \leq p_2 + q_3^\prime \tag{3}$$
We deduce
$$(q_1+q_2+q_3^\prime) + 2 p_2 < q_1 + q_2 + (p_2 + q_3^\prime) \quad\to\quad 2 p_2 < p_2 \tag{4}$$

A contradiction. Therefore, $P$ and $Q$ cannot meet simultaneously anywhere along $\overline{AB}$ (... well ... except for the starting point $A$). $\square$

---

Note that there's nothing special about $Q$'s relative speed, except that it exceeds $P$'s. We can replace all multiplied "$2$"s above with any $k > 1$, and the contradiction stands.

Comment: Will this still hold if the person Q tries to take a straight path from C to E?

Comment: Sure. A detour starting at $C$ simply means that we take $q_2 = 0$. This has no effect on the proof.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for the two persons to meet at a point between A and B on line AB such that none of the persons has to wait for the other one?

Yes, if $C$, $A$, and $B$ be collinear points, in that order, with $\lvert C A \rvert \lt \frac{1}{4} \lvert A B \rvert$. Then, the faster person will catch up with the slower person from behind.

Since the person walking via $C$ is twice as fast as the person walking directly to $B$, they meet at a point $D$ on the line between $A$ and $B$, at distance $2 \lvert CA \rvert$ from $A$ to $B$.

---

What if there is an additional restriction, that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are such that the slower person reaches $B$ before the faster one does?

The restriction can be written as $$2 \lvert A B \rvert \lt \lvert A C \rvert + \lvert C B \rvert$$
but note that the three points must still be collinear for the persons to meet. Without loss of generality, we can choose $A$ to be at origin, $B$ to be at $(b, 0)$ on the positive $x$ axis (so $b \gt 0$), and $C$ to be at $(c, 0)$ on the positive or negative $x$ axis. The restriction can now be written as
$$2 b < \lvert c \rvert + \lvert b - c \rvert$$
There are two solutions to the restriction:
$$c \lt -\frac{b}{2} \quad \text{or} \quad c \gt \frac{3 b}{2}$$

When $c \lt -\frac{b}{2}$, the faster walker will chase the slower walker, but never catch up. (When the faster walker is at $C$, the slower walker is already at least a quarter of the way from $A$ to $B$. When the faster walker is back at $A$, the slower walker is already over half the way from $A$ to $B$.)

When $c \gt \frac{3 b}{2}$, the faster walker will walk initially in front of the slower walker, well past $B$. When the faster walker is at $C$, the slower walker is already at least three quarters of the way from $A$ to $B$. The two will then approach $B$ from opposite sides, and therefore will not meet before both arrive and stop at $B$.